Restriction about tokens per transaction
I want to launch a token on pancakeswap and i want to apply a restriction about buyers, they can not buy more than 100.000 tokens per wallet address.
How can i fix it on pancakeswap
Thanks
Hamoudi

You can do that using openzeppelin library:

install openzeppelin library using npm for example
Open ERC20 implementation and override _beforeTokenTransfer or _transfer function to enforce the restriction.
in the code we're using Ownable. You might want to explore AccessControl as well.

This example code might help:

// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";

contract MyToken is ERC20, Ownable {
    uint256 public maxTokensPerWallet = 100_000 * (10 ** decimals());

    mapping(address => bool) private _isExcludedFromLimit;

    constructor() ERC20("MyToken", "MTK") {
        _mint(msg.sender, 1_000_000_000 * (10 ** decimals())); // Mint 1 billion tokens to the deployer
    }

    function _beforeTokenTransfer(
        address from,
        address to,
        uint256 amount
    ) internal override {
        super._beforeTokenTransfer(from, to, amount);

        // Skip limit checks for minting or burning
        if (from == address(0) || to == address(0)) {
            return;
        }

        // Exclude certain addresses (e.g., owner or liquidity pools)
        if (!_isExcludedFromLimit[to]) {
            uint256 newBalance = balanceOf(to) + amount;
            require(newBalance <= maxTokensPerWallet, "Exceeds max tokens per wallet");
        }
    }

    // Function to exclude specific addresses from the limit (e.g., for PancakeSwap pairs)
    function excludeFromLimit(address account, bool excluded) external onlyOwner {
        _isExcludedFromLimit[account] = excluded;
    }

    // Update the maximum tokens per wallet
    function setMaxTokensPerWallet(uint256 _maxTokens) external onlyOwner {
        maxTokensPerWallet = _maxTokens;
    }
}



maxTokensPerWallet variable specifies the limit.
_beforeTokenTransfer function ensures that no wallet exceeds this limit.
You might need to exclude certain addresses like the PancakeSwap liquidity pool, so the excludeFromLimit function allows the owner to mark those addresses as excluded.
setMaxTokensPerWallet function allows you to update the limit if needed.

Hope this is helpful!
